# function upper than $-2$

Tags: functions

How can I demonstrate this inequation in IR:
$$x-1+\sqrt{{x^2}+2x+3}≥-2\\$$

I did this:
$$x-1+\sqrt{{x^2}+2x+3}+2≥0\\$$
$$x+1+\sqrt{{x^2}+2x+3}≥0\\$$
$$x+1+\sqrt{{x^2}+2x+1+2}≥0\\$$

$$x+1+\sqrt{{(x+1)^2}+2}≥0\\$$

$$\text{if}: x≥0 \implies x+1+\sqrt{{(x+1)^2}+2}≥0\\$$

$$\text{if}: x<0 \implies??\\$$ I don't know what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

$$x-1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+2}>x-1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2}=x-1+|x+1|$$

If $x\ge-1$, we have $x-1+|x+1|=x-1+x+1=2x\ge2(-1)$.

If $x<-1$, we have $x-1+|x+1|=x-1-1-x=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

You may write:

$$(x+1)^2+2\geq(x+1)^2$$

$$\sqrt {x^2+2x+3}\geq -(x+1)$$

$$x+1 +\sqrt {x^2+2x+3}\geq 0$$

This is what you found by reducing.